# Sorting a hash first by value then by key

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash

I have a hash [sic]:

```
[
  ["a", 1], 
  ["b", 1], 
  ["d", 1], 
  ["k", 1], 
  ["r", 1], 
  ["f", 2], 
  ["j", 2], 
  ["o", 2], 
  ["i", 3], 
  ["s", 3]
]
```

I want the output to be sorted by the numbers from smallest to largest, and then by the alphabet in reverse order:

```
[
  ["r", 1], 
  ["k", 1], 
  ["d", 1], 
  ["b", 1], 
  ["a", 1], 
  ["o", 2], 
  ["j", 2], 
  ["f", 2], 
  ["s", 3], 
  ["i", 3]
]
```

Is there a way to do this?

This is my code:

```
def letter_counts(word)
  my_hash = Hash.new(0)
  word.split("").each{|word| my_hash[word] += 1}
  my_hash.sort_by{|key,value| [value, key]}
end
```

Comment: please include your code in the question and not through a link.

Comment: How is `letter_counts` used? How is that related to your "hash"?

Comment: @BriExpost: Your code doesn't show a Hash. It shows an Array.

Answer (score 4):

Group the elements in the array by each last element (the integer ones), map them by sorting each group by its first element, and then reverse:

```
def hsort(array)
  array.group_by(&:last).flat_map { |_, v| v.sort_by(&:first).reverse }
end

p hsort([["a", 1], ["b", 1], ["d", 1], ["k", 1], ["r", 1], ["f", 2], ["j", 2], ["o", 2], ["i", 3], ["s", 3]])
# [["r", 1], ["k", 1], ["d", 1], ["b", 1], ["a", 1], ["o", 2], ["j", 2], ["f", 2], ["s", 3], ["i", 3]]
p hsort([["e", 1], ["b", 1], ["d", 1], ["k", 1], ["r", 1], ["f", 2], ["j", 2], ["o", 2], ["i", 3], ["s", 3]])
# [["r", 1], ["k", 1], ["e", 1], ["d", 1], ["b", 1], ["o", 2], ["j", 2], ["f", 2], ["s", 3], ["i", 3]]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
h = {"b"=>1, "j"=>2, "r"=>1, "o"=>2, "k"=>1, "a"=>1, "s"=>3, "i"=>3, "f"=>2, "d"=>1}

h.max_by(h.size) { |k,v| [-v,k] }
  #=> [["r", 1], ["k", 1], ["d", 1], ["b", 1], ["a", 1],
  #    ["o", 2], ["j", 2], ["f", 2],
  #    ["s", 3], ["i", 3]]
```

This uses the form of [Enumerable#max_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) that takes an argument, which here is the number of key-value pairs in the hash. Note that `max_by` (and `min_by`, `max` and `min`) were first permitted to have an argument in Ruby v2.2.

Answer (score 1):

```
[
  ["a", 1], 
  ["b", 1], 
  ["d", 1], 
  ["k", 1], 
  ["r", 1], 
  ["f", 2], 
  ["j", 2], 
  ["o", 2], 
  ["i", 3], 
  ["s", 3]
]
.sort_by{|k, v| [v, -k.ord]}
```

Output:

```
[
  ["r", 1],
  ["k", 1],
  ["d", 1],
  ["b", 1],
  ["a", 1],
  ["o", 2],
  ["j", 2],
  ["f", 2],
  ["s", 3],
  ["i", 3]
]
```

Comment: Clever! Must remember that. (It requires "keys" to be strings of size 1, but that seems to be what the OP has.)